# Unable to activate "Enable Wireless"

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, iwlwifi, toshiba

It's my first time installing Linux (Ubuntu) at my desktop, and it seems not to be a good start.

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, in a Toshiba, but I'm unable to activate Wireless network, via **System Settings > Network** or any other way. Cable works fine!

I've tried to use `rfkill unblock`, different kernel, checked BIOS and still doesn't work. I believe I've tried it all, but I'm not that experienced. I hope you can help me.

```
------------lspci -v 
04:00.0 Network controller:
   Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN   
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
Memory at c2600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied> 
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi   Kernel
modules: iwlwifi

-------------rfkill list
0: Toshiba Bluetooth:
Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

--------sudo lshw -C network *-network               
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    product: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
    logical name: wlp4s0
    version: 34
    serial: 88:53:2e:07:5d:5a
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no
```

multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
        resources: irq:34 memory:c2600000-c2601fff

Comment: Is there a wireless key combination or switch, sometimes called Airplane Mode, on that laptop? It appears to be set to disable wireless.

Comment: The hardware switch Fn+F8 is on. I've tried to play with this and the rfkill output changes., but the result doesn't. :(

Comment: May we see: `lsmod | grep tosh` Also, what does the switch change in: `rfkill list all`?

Comment: lsmod | grep tosh
toshiba_acpi           45056  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 toshiba_acpi
industrialio           69632  1 toshiba_acpi
wmi                    16384  1 toshiba_acpi
toshiba_haps           16384  0
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
video                  40960  2 toshiba_acpi,i915

Comment: The switch changes the wireless lan soft blocked.rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
blgr@Reis:~$ rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe -r toshiba_acpi && sudo rfkill unblock all && rfkill list all` Is there any improvement? If so, I will propose a permanent fix.

Comment: Thanks but no it didn't improve. I've already tried to unblock with rfkill. Nothing happens with the unblock command(i also found it strange?!?).   sudo modprobe -r toshiba_acpi
 sudo rfkill unblock all
 rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Is there still no change in Hard blocked:yes as you press Fn+F8?

Comment: When i press Fn+F8 the rfkill gets on, like previous post. But the System Settings->Network doesn't allow me to activate Wireless.

Comment: Correction: Now if i press Fn+F8 it doesn't change anything in rfkill output. It stays like bellow.     rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: I am almost out of ideas. You might try post #19 here as crazy as it sounds: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364655&highlight=toshiba I expect part of the fix is resetting the BIOS to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

It worked!!! Not like suggested in the thread you mentioned but like in [www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/44040-43-wireless-function-working-toshiba-satellite](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/44040-43-wireless-function-working-toshiba-satellite)

> So, first disconnect your laptop from power, remove the battery, and
>   press the power up button while holding it down for atleast 30
>   seconds. i know it sounds weird, but that's what i thought at first,
>   and it worked. Ofcourse while holding down the power button, nothing
>   will come on as there is no power source. after you're done, put the
>   battery back on and connect the laptop to power, then switch on the
>   laptop, your wifi should be working.

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This dont work at all!